# Java/Android: DatagramChannel is already set non-blocking, receive() still blocks

Tags: java, android

I set the `datagramchannel` non-blocking by instance method `configureBlocking(false)`,
But when I use instance method `receive(buffer)`, it still hangs there for incoming packet. Anyone could tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems this is an Android bug!
See these links for possible workarounds: * http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16579 * http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12328